# Sql Server Server 2008 r2 Installation Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition on Windows Server 2012. Unexpectedly I come across the error shown below. Installation successfully completes.

Can someone help me identify the problem and resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Should this be tagged with windows 2012?  See this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-package-manager-error-message-with/459d7051-a0da-4f0b-a3aa-e91fa36f496b) which is discussing the same error.

Comment: [Using SQL Server in Windows 8 and later versions of Windows operating system](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2681562/using-sql-server-in-windows-8-and-later-versions-of-windows-operating-system), so SQL Server 2008 R2 is supported on Microsoft Windows Server 2012. Ensure you have .Net Framework 3.5 installed and run the Service Pack 2 for SQL Server 2008 R2 after you have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 (even better would be a slip-streamed installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 w/ SP2)